# How to make a whole chapter DRAFTED with watermarks

Tags: chapters, watermark

I'm writing a report in LaTeX using Overleaf.

I got several chapters, but I want to mark only two of them with “DRAFT”. 
I have tried the `\usepackage{draftwatermark}`, but then the watermark appears on every chapter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Comment: Hello Amalie! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] overleaf tag as this is not directly overleaf-related. I hope the answer below helps you solve the issue!

Answer (score 2):

The `draftwatermark` package has several macros to customise the watermark. You could use these to temporarily set the watermark to something invisible. For example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\SetWatermarkText{}
\section{One}
\lipsum
\clearpage

\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\section{Two}
\lipsum
\clearpage

\SetWatermarkText{}
\section{Three}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is i not possible to use a code to only get draft on 1 chapter, instead of all chapters?
Do i really have to ''remove'' draft from all other chapters after using the userpackage?

Comment: You don’t have to remove it from all other chapters separately. If you set `\SetWatermarkText{}`, it just stays this way. So it is enough to just put it once after chapter 1 (or before chapter 2).